# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gpuarray.lib'

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to get my Theano running on Windows 10 64bit, by [following this](https://ankivil.com/installing-keras-theano-and-dependencies-on-windows-10/) tutorial however I get the error of:

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported or is too old (version 0.7 or higher required)
NoneType: None
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 11.546832 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879337  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323284]
Used the cpu
```

which obviously says my GPU cannot be used. Apparently my pygpu is not working correctly (although I installed it via Anaconda and it should be enough but anyway). I found out that one needs to install [libgpuarray](http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html) as well. I followed the instructions (used CMAKE latest version with Visual Studio 12 2013 x64 settings) and I compiled & built it correctly.

However the following command to set it up:

```
 python setup.py build
```

gives me:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gpuarray.lib'
```

No matter what I did I could not find a solution to this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured out. One needs to point out the location of the `.lib` file as well, which can be done with the command:

```
python setup.py build_ext -L C:\Users\name\libgpuarray\lib\Debug
```